# Multiprocessing in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, multiprocessing, azure-functions

I have a Azure function which gets triggered by queue message. In this function we want to access multiple blobs concurrently using multiprocessing. Can this be done in azure functions?

Thanks

Comment: Use an `async def` function and the asyncio client in this library: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider what type of service plan you are going to run in. If it's a consumption plan then you will only have a single CPU core to do any processing so will be limited on the amount of parallel processing you can do. If you want to process a lot of files in parallel and want to get the most out of Azure functions I would advise you look at Durable functions in particular [Fan Out/Fan In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup).

You can create an Orchestrator and then create an activity function to process each blob and the system will scale up and add instances (at a cost obviously) as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing is possible thanks to the fact that python has a base package that accomplishes just that.

--Edit--

However for the thing you are trying to accomplish I would recommend using asyncio https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

A function in azure is just another computer executing the code you tell it to execute.

Look up examples here: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

PS: However I have to advise you, azure functions charge money per time processing so you test really well before starting the function.