# Python multiprocessing library in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure-functions, python-multiprocessing

I have python code that uses *multiprocessing* to speed up some processing. We are considering starting using Azure Functions. How *multiprocessing* library would behave in an Azure Function? If we deploy our current code will Azure (with *multiprocessing*) do the split over cores the same way as it's done on a standard machine?

Comment: how it runs serverless and how it runs on a machine is different. The Functions runtime automatically manages the scaling of your functions based on incoming requests. Unlike multiprocessing on a single machine where processes can share memory, Functions executions are isolated and do not share memory or state by default. If you are asking how multiprocessing library of python would behave in a function, thats another question, with another answer.

Comment: Check these questions/answers: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188727/multiprocessing-in-azure-functions

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61688427/how-do-language-workers-work-in-azure-functions-using-python

Comment: this talks about async: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/python-scale-performance-reference

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @ZiyaMertKarakas for your answers. How multiprocessing library would behave in an Azure Function is exactly what I'm asking. Corrected the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **@Ziya Mert Karakas -**

Azure Functions can execute Python code. By design, a Python host instance can only handle one function call at once.
The [`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT - 1-10`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/python-scale-performance-reference.md#use-multiple-language-worker-processes) in **application setting** allows you to increase the number of worker processes per host (up to 10). Python versions 3.10, 3.9, and  are supported by Azure Functions.

> Note- `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` does not work with Python v2 function

To increase throughput, Azure Functions also enables memory sharing between your out-of-process Python language worker and the Functions host process. By adding an application setting with the name `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_SHARED_MEMORY_DATA_TRANSFER_ENABLED and a value of 1,` **you can enable shared memory when your function app has bottlenecks.** Once shared memory is enabled, you may adjust the shared memory to a size of **256 MB** by using the `DOCKER_SHM_SIZE` parameter.

In conclusion, you can run Python code using Azure Functions, but ***you should avoid utilising the multiprocessing library and instead use asyncio for parallelism.*** Additionally, you can boost performance by raising the number of worker processes per host.

***Sample http trigger code with  async method & asyncio library:-***

```py
import logging
import asyncio
import azure.functions as func

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = await req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed asynchronously.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Query String",
             status_code=400
        )
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Sample function multiprocessing module with spawn start method:-

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import azure.functions as func

def worker():
    # your multiprocessing code here
    pass

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # create a new process for each function invocation
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    p = ctx.Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    return func.HttpResponse("Hello from Azure Functions!")
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[azure-docs/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-python.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-python.md)

[azure-docs/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-python.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs (github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-reference-python.md)

Comment: Note- FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT does not work with Python v2 function -> was there a fix? I've just conducted a test and it seems to be working just fine (http triggered Azure Function, Python V2 stack).